# How to add height to HTML5 canvas without clearing the canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, height

I want to make an option for my drawing app to add height with a click.
Ps. I don't want to resize the entire canvas just add height down, leaving the drawings without distortions.

Comment: you can't change canvas width and height properties without clearing it. However you can easily call again your drawings on the resized canvas, or even use a second, offset canvas, draw the original one on it, resize the original one and redraw back the cached one on the resized canvas using `ctx.drawImage(canvas, x, y)` or use a container div, with hidden overflow and change the size of this container.

Comment: As @Kaiido correctly says, the canvas content will automatically be cleared if you resize the canvas element (`canvasElement.width=newWidth`). I guess you could initially create an extra tall canvas element and put it in a shorter div container and use CSS to initially show the top portion of the canvas. That way you could "reveal" more of the canvas as needed without having to resize its height.